# eclipse does not list details about second class in outline, as well i can't put break point in the second class in the same file

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I am trying to put a break point in a (any) method of TimerThread class. Its in java.util package .
Note that i don't have source code (is it because its JDK library and that's why source code not open source?) and i am using a decompiler(CFR) which shows me the decompiled code of the Timer.class in eclipse.

Timer.class has three classes in it.

1. public class Timer {
2. class TimerThread extends Thread {
3. class TaskQueue {

When i try to put breakpoint in any of the methods of the First class - Timer, i am able to put breakpoint.
But, for the second and third classes (TimerThread and TaskQueue), i can't put breakpoints in any of their methods. As well, eclipse does not list those two classes in the outline view.

Is there anything i can do to be able to put breakpoints in there?

Comment: The JDK should include the source for these (I am looking at the source using JDK 14.0.1). Eclipse appears to be happy to set breakpoints anywhere.

Comment: Make sure in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ a JDK instead of a JRE is configured (a JDK is a JRE with some additional tools and with the source code of the system library). You don't need a decompiler for this. But when using a decompiler, be aware that nested classes are compiled to separate files.

Comment: Didn't know jdk has a src.zip within it. i am somewhat new to java. Great help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i want to mark both  the answers as helpful, but i can see your answers as comments, there is only a flag that i can press to mark abuse, there is no button i see that i can "upvote" or "mark as answer"